# UILabel won't center in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel, drawrect

I'm trying to create a custom `UIView` that can be used as a progress bar or similar (`@IBDesignable` with `IBInspectable`s). I want a centered (primarily X-axis, but for now Y as well) `UILabel` in this view.

```
private func addLabel()
{
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width / 4, self.frame.height / 4))
    label.center = self.center
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    label.text = "5"
    //Color just to see the whole label
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
    self.addSubview(label)
}
```

In Interfacebuilder the label centers just fine:

[image: Interface Builder centered label]

However, when running it on my device (iPhone 5S) the label is aligned slightly to the right (picture below). I've tried different approaches (like making the label frame `self.frame`) but it's still not centered correctly. What am I missing?

[image: UILabel on device]

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height)
    let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)
    let startAngle: CGFloat = π
    let endAngle: CGFloat = 2 * π

    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius / 2 - arcWidth / 2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
    path.lineWidth = arcWidth

    arcBackgroundColor.setStroke()
    path.stroke()

    self.addLayer()
}

private func addLayer()
{
    progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    progressLayer.path = self.path.CGPath
    progressLayer.strokeColor = self.progressColor.CGColor
    progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    progressLayer.lineWidth = self.arcWidth

    if animatesOnDraw && progress > 0 {
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
        self.animateProgress(0)

    } else {
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(self.progress / self.maxValue)
        progressLayer.opacity = Float(self.progressStrokeEndValue)
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }


        addLabel() //as shown above

}
```

Comment: Align UILabel centre through Autolayouts in Nib/Storyboard file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `label.center = self.center`, because the center of the label and the center of the superview are in different coordinate systems so they might not be the same. Use instead

```
label.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y:self.view.frame.bounds.size.height / 2.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.label.center = view.center
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the UILabel programatically and Modify the UILabel frame from

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width / 4, self.frame.height / 4))
```

To

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.frame.width/2 - (self.frame.height/4)/2, 0, self.frame.width / 4, self.frame.height / 4))
```

**ELSE**

Implement Autolayout

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be:-

```
@IBOutlet customView : UIView! 
//Let customView be the outlet of your custom view

func addLabel () {
    let CenterY = customView.center.y
    let CenterX = customView.center.x
    let heightOfCustom = customView.frame.size.height
    let widthOfCustom = customView.frame.size.width
    // If you want a label with height and width 1/4th of the width of the custom view
    let label = UILabel(frame : CGRectMake(CenterX - widthOfCustom/8, CenterY - heightOfCustom/8, widthOfCustom/4, heightOfCustom/4))
    label.text = "5"
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
    self.addSubview(label)
}
```